# Android Runtime Exception: Unable to instantiate activity componentInfo?

Tags: android, instantiation

i am running a list-fragment program and at run-time i got the below error.

**Error:**

```
**02-09 09:03:40.213: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(572): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{ni.android.Fragment/ni.android.Fragment.Fragment}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ni.android.Fragment.Fragment in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/ni.android.Fragment-1.apk]**
```

I don't know the reason.My program contains three classes- DetailsFragment.java,  FragmentsTitles.java and Shakespear.java can any one help me out please....

Comment: Look further down your stack trace for the "Caused by" portion, which should indicate your actual problem.

Comment: It has caused because of below LogCAt:  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.fragmenttest/com.example.fragmenttest.FragmentTestActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class fragment
02-10 06:00:21.938: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(535): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class fragment
02-10 06:00:21.938: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(535): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.fragmenttest.FragmentTestActivity cannot be cast to android.app.Fragment

Comment: **Shakespeare**, not Shakespear :p

Answer (score 18):

At any time if you get an error stating **Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo**
That means your code has some error.
That error will be shown in log cat As **Caused by:.........**
1.**Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class fragment**(This indicates that there is an error in xml and the activity has inflating problem.
By this you can know what is the error and if you rectify that error then your problem will be solved.

Comment: I think any error starting with **Unable to** has also a **Caused by** information.

Comment: if I could vote this answer up more than once, I'll definitely do.

Answer (score 5):

This blog will solve this issue.

http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/how-to-fix-the-classdefnotfounderror-with-adt-17

Thanks

Comment: If you are updating to ADT 17 definately do this it worked for me and i already looked at all the other "stupid" things it can be.

Comment: I love the solution. I've search and try about 10 different solutions and this is the one (at least, the one if you have updated to ADT 17)

Answer (score 1):

I had this error as well (beginner) and I noticed that I forgot to create the onCreate method in my activity class. Once I created that, the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

If you have like this warning before error:

```
05-16 10:08:00.033: W/dalvikvm(1695): Unable to resolve superclass of Lmy/fragment/test/FragmentTestActivity; (7)
05-16 10:08:00.076: W/dalvikvm(1695): Link of class 'Lmy/fragment/test/FragmentTestActivity;' failed
```

Should export android-support-v4 to right to your app:
Configure Java Build Path -> Order And Export tab -> set checkbox android-support-v4.jar

(Maybe need to remove existing one firstly)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not only looking at error logcat ... as the error may be seen using verbose.  But I agree with @parameshwar-s